# Is prohibited melacha on chol hamoed issur hanaah

Tags: halacha, melacha-creative-work, chol-hamoed, orach-chaim, issurei-hanaa

In Halacha, if a Jew does a form of melacha that is prohibited on chol hamoed, is what is created from that melacha issur hanaah after the fact? Or no, is it unlike Shabbat and it can be benefited from after the fact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R’ Wosner in [Shevet Halevi 6:68](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1416&st=&pgnum=72) discusses this exact question. He concludes that it depends on the machlokes if the issur melocho is biblical or rabbinical. If it’s doraisa, then it would be assur to benefit, if it’s rabbinical, it would be permitted.

In Shmiras Shabbos K’hilchoso, Perek 68 footnote 44, he says that R’ Shlomo Zalman held even if it’s only rabbinical, it would still be prohibited. He says it’s similar to taking teruma or toiveling a kli on Shabbos, which are drabbanan and still assur to benefit from it.